# flask peewee how to change the field order when edit/creating forms

Tags: flask, peewee, flask-admin

For a model `User` I want to put an inline model `ProjectNotes` in it, and how 
 can I change the fields order when creating or editing it?
 For example, change the order to `ProjectNotes, username, email.`(See pic below.)

```
class User(BaseModel):
   username = peewee.CharField(max_length=80)
   email = peewee.CharField(max_length=120)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.username

class ProjectNotes(BaseModel):
   comment = peewee.CharField(max_length=64)
   user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return '%s - %s' % (self.comment)

class UserAdmin(ModelView):
   inline_models = (ProjectNotes,)

admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [pass additional attributes](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_peewee/#flask_admin.contrib.peewee.ModelView.inline_models) such as `form_columns`, `form_label`, `column_labels` for `inline_models` as a dictionary:

```
class UserAdmin(ModelView):
    inline_models = [
        (ProjectNotes, {'form_columns': ('user', 'comment')})
    ]
```

Or create form class for your `ProjectNotes` model:

```
from flask_admin.model.form import InlineFormAdmin

class ProjectNotesAdmin(InlineFormAdmin):
    form_columns = ('user', 'comment')

class UserAdmin(ModelView):
    inline_models = [ProjectNotesAdmin(ProjectNotes)]
```

I also found out that I need to specify primary key column in `form_columns` for `flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView`. Don't know if you need to do the same thing for `flask_admin.contrib.peewee.ModelView`.

Comment: Thanks and I tried both the methods but the same error occurs: `AttributeError: 'ProjectNotesForm' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: @Samoth Then it looks like `peewee.ModelView` has the same issue as `sqla.ModelView`. Is there 'id' column in your `ProjectNotes` model? Try to specify 'id' column in your `form_columns`.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin: No, there is no `id` in my `ProjectNotes` model, but I can add it and try again.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin: After adding `id ` there is no errors but the order is not show as I wanted to: I tried `inline_models = [
        (ProjectNotes, {'form_columns': ('id', 'comment', 'user')})
    ]`

Comment: @Samoth It looks like peewee implicitly adds 'id' column. You've done right by adding 'id' explicitly. Now you just need to change order: `('id', 'comment', 'user')` is the same order as before :)

Comment: Thanks , and I am trying to order all columns including other model's column , such as `('username', 'id', 'comment', 'user','email')`